# Search command button on userform not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a search button on a userform.  I want 3 things to happen.  If the user selects the Search button without putting any text in TextBox6, I want a msgbox to popup and tell them they need to add a customer code.  If they enter a customer code that is not in the excel spreadsheet and select the Search button, I want a msgbox to popup and tell them that customer code doesn't exist.  When they select OK I want TextBox6 to clear and the cursor to have focus set on TextBox6.  If they enter a code in TextBox6 that is in the excel spreadsheet and select the Search button, I want that record to populate the userform.  I am using the code below, and it works for scenario 1 and 2 above.  But when the code exists in the excel spreadsheet, after it populates the userform the msgbox that says the that customer code doesn't exist still popsup.  Can you adjust my code so that doesn't happen?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range

On Error GoTo Err

     'validate text box
If TextBox6.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Customer Code"
    Cancel = True
   Me.TextBox6.SetFocus

    Else
row_number = 0

Do
DoEvents

row_number = row_number + 1

items_in_review = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & row_number)

If items_in_review = TextBox6.Text Then
    TextBox1.Text = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & row_number)
    TextBox2.Text = Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & row_number)
    TextBox3.Text = Sheets("sheet1").Range("D" & row_number)
    TextBox4.Text = Sheets("sheet1").Range("F" & row_number)
    TextBox5.Text = Sheets("sheet1").Range("H" & row_number)
    TextBox7.Text = Sheets("sheet1").Range("I" & row_number)
    TextBox8.Text = Sheets("sheet1").Range("G" & row_number)

 Me.TextBox7.Visible = True
 Me.Label8.Visible = True

End If
Loop Until items_in_review = ""

    MsgBox "Customer Code not Found"
        Cancel = True
    UserForm1.TextBox6.Value = ""
    TextBox6.SetFocus

Exit Sub

Err:
MsgBox Err.Description
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to clear the search box if something is not found: as a user it's annoying if you have to retype the whole thing just because you made a typo...

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range, v

On Error GoTo Err

'validate text box
v = Trim(TextBox6.Value)
If Len(v) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Customer Code"
    Cancel = True
    Me.TextBox6.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End if

Set aCell = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(v, lookat:=xlWhole)

if not aCell is Nothing Then

    with aCell.EntireRow

        TextBox1.Text = .Cells(,"B").Value
        TextBox2.Text = .Cells(,"C").Value
        TextBox3.Text = .Cells(,"D").Value
        TextBox4.Text = .Cells(,"F").Value
        TextBox5.Text = .Cells(,"H").Value
        TextBox7.Text = .Cells(,"I").Value
        TextBox8.Text = .Cells(,"G").Value

    end with

    Me.TextBox7.Visible = True
    Me.Label8.Visible = True

else
    MsgBox "Customer Code not Found"
    Cancel = True
    'UserForm1.TextBox6.Value = "" 'don't do this!
    TextBox6.SetFocus
end if

Exit Sub

Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim...thank you for your help...works perfect.  Thanks for the suggestion on not clearing the search box.